Connecting matplotlib to tkinter and using it
I wrote code that draws a picture using blit when you click on the screen.
When matplotlib is used alone, it works normally.
However, when connected to tkinter, the click event is not delivered.
When lambda is used, a click event is sent, but the picture is not drawn.
Also, if you connect an event without a lambda, the callback will not work.
What's the problem?
import tkinter as tk

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection


xy = [
    [
        (0, 0),
        (1, 1),
        (2, 2),
        (3, 3),
        (4, 2),
        (5, 1),
        (6, 0),
    ],
    [
        (7, 0),
        (8, 1),
        (9, 2),
        (10, 3),
        (11, 2),
        (12, 1),
        (13, 0),
    ],
]

class Blit:
    bg = None
    cbg = False
    was_draw = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
        self.canvas: FigureCanvasAgg = self.fig.canvas
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, 20)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
        self.lc = LineCollection(xy, edgecolors=['y', 'b'], facecolors=['r', 'g'], alpha=[0.2, 1], linewidth=15, animated=True)
        self.ax.add_collection(self.lc)
        self.connect_event()
        return

    def connect_event(self):
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.draw_artist)
        return

    def create_bg(self):
        if self.cbg: return
        self.cbg = True
        self.bg = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.fig.bbox)
        self.cbg = False
        return

    def draw_artist(self, _):
        print()
        print('draw_artist')
        if not self.bg: self.create_bg()
        self.canvas.restore_region(self.bg)
        if self.was_draw:
            self.was_draw = False
            self.lc.set_visible(False)
            return self.blit()
        print('draw')
        self.was_draw = True
        self.lc.set_visible(True)
        return self.blit()

    def blit(self):
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.lc)
        self.canvas.blit()
        return


class TkBlit:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.f = tk.Frame(master)
        self.f.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.b = Blit()
        tkagg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.b.fig, self.f)
        tkagg.draw()
        widget = tkagg.get_tk_widget()
        # if use lambda, event work.
        # self.b.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda x: self.b.draw_artist(x))
        widget.grid(column=0, row=0)

        return


plt.switch_backend('tkagg')
b = Blit()
plt.show()

window = tk.Tk()
TkBlit(window)
window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda *_: (plt.close('all'), window.destroy()))

window.mainloop()


